# OneToMany prevent checking for proxy object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to improve the performance of a repository-method. I have a OneToMany-relationship in one of my entities, UserEntity, with a set of AddressEntities that are loaded lazily.

In AddressEntity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = EntityConstants.COLUMN_USER_ID, referencedColumnName = EntityConstants.COLUMN_USER_ID)
private UserEntity user;
```

In UserEntity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
```

The problem is that when I fetch AddressEntity, a query is made to the database to the user table as well. From what I understand this is to check for the existence of the UserEntity, and to create a proxy object to it.

This takes time, and I am not interested in whether or not the user entity exists in this case. Is there any way to prevent hibernate to do this extra query and simply leave userEntity to null?

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you fetch `AddressEntity` ?

Comment: perhaps if your provider used bytecode enhancement then it wouldn't need such checks (like other JPA providers)? but then you likely could configure that to happen ...

Comment: Hibernate either create a proxy and do not query the database, or it fetches the record (but does not create a proxy). It can't do both.

Comment: @Berger Another query I have `"LEFT JOIN FETCH d.address "`, and that that entity I have     
`@JoinColumn(name = EntityConstants.COLUMN_ADDRESS_ID, referencedColumnName = EntityConstants.COLUMN_ADDRESS_ID)
    private AddressEntity address;`

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Thanks, but I don't want it to do both, I want it to do neither.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by only selecting the attributes that I needed:

```
SELECT ad.longitude, ad.latitude FROM AddressEntity ad
```

This does not cause hibernate to check for proxy objects on relations that are not selected.